# react-native-iap Native module cannot be null

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-iap

I just ejected from expo because i wanted to use react-native-iap.
I installed that module and then cd ios > pod install
but after doing that i'm getting an error says "Native module cannot be null"
I'm sure that the error because of this module because when i remove it's import statement, the error goes away.
any solution?
Thanks

Comment: i am also getting the same issue on ios. Working fine on android.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps (manual linking from Xcode worked for me)

1: Add "RNIap.xcodeproj" in the Libraries folder.

2: Add "libRNLap.a" ,Target -> build phases -> link binary with libraries -> click on + icon -> and select libRNIap.a